# Append to list while in recursive loop

Tags: python, recursion

I'm trying to create a recursive function that takes a JSON dictionary and stores any value with key names 'rate' into a list. I will then take that list and find the lowest value. My code looks like this right now, but is producing multiple empty lists within the list.

```
def recurse_keys(df):
    rates = []
    for key, value in df.items():
        if key == 'rate':
            rates.append(value)
        if isinstance(df[key], dict):
            recurse_keys(df[key])
```

Comment: Because you're doing `rates = []` on each recursive call.

Comment: pass rates as an argument to the recursive function

Comment: Each time you call `recurse_keys`, it's creating a new `rates` list which is initially empty.  Presumably this is not what you want.

Comment: @MarounMaroun I don't think that's the problem, the problem is that nothing is returned and that the result from the recursive calls is discarded.

Comment: @timgeb correct, missed that.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to combine the results from the recursion, and return it:

```
def recurse_keys(df):
    rates = []
    for key, value in df.items():
        if key == 'rate':
            rates.append(value)
        if isinstance(df[key], dict):
            rates += recurse_keys(df[key])
    return rates
```

Comment: @Casey `df[key]` and `value` are the same, no? Is there a reason to mix?

Comment: @Fabricator is this method preferred over the suggested below (passing `rates`)? This method would seem less intuitive, but maybe I'm wrong?

Comment: @Jason, both methods work. I prefer to use fewer arguments. Plus this required minimum change from OP's original code.

Comment: @Jason I think you are right. They are the same value. I'll fix that.

Answer (score 2):

1. extend your result list with the result from the recursive call
2. don't forget to return your result

Code:

```
def recurse_keys(df):
    rates = []
    for key, value in df.items():
        if key == 'rate':
            rates.append(value)
        if isinstance(df[key], dict):
            rates += recurse_keys(df[key])
    return rates
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also initialize the rates list outside of the recursive function and pass it to the function, as `list` is a mutable datastructure, it'll be passed as reference. Like this (not tested though):

```
def recurse_keys(df, rates):
    for key, value in df.items():
        if key == 'rate':
            rates.append(value)
        if isinstance(df[key], dict):
            recurse_keys(df[key], rates)

def calling_method():
    rates = [] 
    recurse_keys(df, rates)
```

Answer (score 0):

you need pass rates as rates, it seems in every recursion you do create new rates list.

```
def recurse_keys(df, rates=[]):
    for key, value in df.items():
        if key == 'rate':
            rates.append(value)
        if isinstance(df[key], dict):
            recurse_keys(df[key], rates)
    return rates

result = recurse_keys(df)
min(result)
```

Comment: be very careful about that mutable default argument

Comment: Please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-in-python-the-mutable-default-argument.

Comment: I have never faced problem with this usage but it does not mean I will not indeed, thanks @Rogalski, @ timgeb. I will be more careful.

Comment: @ŁukaszRogalski I checked that and several other pages linked in there! it made me realise that in this example simply calling `recurse_keys(df[key])` instead of `recurse_keys(df[key], rates)` would still work, but only the first time it is called.